# SSIS merge join lacks row (and also How to simulate SSIS join with tsql query)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In my project I have a merge join transformation, that uses inner join. It is supposed to join the files lookup with the rest of the data flow. However, the join seems to not include some rows, with files, even though it should? I'm trying to simulate the join in tsql, but I seem to be doing it wrong as it shows me the missing rows.

Here are the outputs I'm trying to join
Input A:

```
SELECT *
FROM
tblExpense expense
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM tblExpenseDtl Details
    WHERE expense.intExpenseID = Details.intExpenseID
    ORDER BY Details.sintLineNo
) details
WHERE
expense.dtUpdateDateTime > '2017-06-01'
ORDER BY expense.intExpenseID desc
```

Input B:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM dbo.tblExpense e
JOIN tblExpenseDtl d ON d.intExpenseID = e.intExpenseID
JOIN tblExpReceiptFile f ON f.intExpenseDtlID = d.intExpenseDtlID
WHERE
e.dtUpdateDateTime > '2017-06-01'
ORDER BY e.intExpenseID desc
```

And the sql query that I thought would produce the same result as my SSIS inner join

```
SELECT *
FROM
tblExpense expense
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM tblExpenseDtl Details
    WHERE expense.intExpenseID = Details.intExpenseID
    ORDER BY Details.sintLineNo
) details
inner join ( SELECT f.*
    FROM dbo.tblExpense e
    JOIN tblExpenseDtl d ON d.intExpenseID = e.intExpenseID
    JOIN tblExpReceiptFile f ON f.intExpenseDtlID = d.intExpenseDtlID
    WHERE
    e.dtUpdateDateTime > '2017-06-01'
    ORDER BY e.intExpenseID desc
) innerJ
WHERE
expense.dtUpdateDateTime > '2017-06-01'
ORDER BY expense.intExpenseID desc
```

The join key in the SSIS is the `expense.intExpenseID = e.intExpenseID`.

Input A gives 1 row, with an expenseID=X, and input B gives 2 rows with an expenseID=X

Comment: Why you are going to use a merge join when you can do everything in a OLE DB source with a SQL command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you sorting data before merging it? According to [this](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/03/sorting-in-sql-vs-sorting-in-ssis.html) SSIS is sorting in different way than SQL Server (in most cases). Maybe there is a problem.
Edit: What type is intExpenseID?

Comment: they are sorted by intExpenseID, which, as name suggests, is an int. There shouldn't be any problems with case sensitivity

Comment: @Xyzk Ok. Where are you sorting data?

Comment: Okay, so I did it according to the msdn specification and sorted by adding order by in my sql query (as specified above). However, for whatever reason, the inner join did not work properly with those sorts. When I added sort component, as suggested by article you linked to, it started to work fine. I have no idea why, when i'm sorting ints, but thank you

Comment: @Xyzk Great, but this is totally weird. Could you check metadata of both Id columns? Maybe one is four-byte integer and the other one is eight-byte?